# how to find the second number in a string with Regex expression

Tags: regex, expression, qregularexpression

I want a regular expression that finds the last match.

the result that I want is "103-220898-44"

The expression that I'm using is `([^\d]|^)\d{3}-\d{6}-\d{2}([^\d]|$)`. This doesn't work because it matches the first result "100-520006-90" and I want the last "103-220898-44"

**Example A**
Transferencia exitosa
Comprobante No. 0000065600
26 May 2022 - 03:32 p.m.
Producto origen
Cuenta de Ahorro
Ahorros
100-520006-90
Producto destino
nameeee nene
Ahorros / ala
103-220898-44
Valor enviado
$ 1.000.00

Comment: What do you mean with *"it works in the example B but not in example A"*? The only difference I see is that in A there are two matches, and in B there is just one...

Comment: I don't know if is possible but in example A I want the second match, can this be achieve by specifying the line breaks ?

Comment: What is the logic by which you want the **second** match? What is special about it? Or what is wrong with the first one?

Comment: the second number(second match) is the account I always want to make the transaction not the first number(first match), this is always an account I know. that's why I always want the second match

Comment: *"I always want the second match"*: So since there is no second match in B, that means you *don't* want to match anything in B, right?

Comment: Guess the last match in each block? Try e.g. [`^\d{3}-\d{6}-\d{2}$(?!\n(?:.+\n)*\d+-)`](https://regex101.com/r/zLuWWS/1)

Comment: To be more clear in example B I want the first math since if you see the possible first match is hidden and the add 100-5* "*" but in example A the fist match I don't need it, I need the second match

Comment: Do you want the second match, or the last match before an empty line?

Comment: You are right I want the last match

Answer (score 0):

```
/.*(\d{3}-\d{6}-\d{2})(?:[^\d]|$)/gs
```

If you add `.*` to the beginning of your regex, it only captures the last one since it's greedy. Also, you need to use the single-line regex flag (`s`) to capture new lines by using `.*`.

Note: I replaced some `(...)` strings with `(?:...)` since their aim is grouping, not capturing.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fygL1X/2

```js
const regex = new RegExp('.*(\\d{3}-\\d{6}-\\d{2})(?:[^\\d]|$)', 'gs')

const str = `ransferencia exitosa
Comprobante No. 0000065600
26 May 2022 - 03:32 p.m.
Producto origen
Cuenta de Ahorro
Ahorros
100-520006-90
Producto destino
nameeee nene
Ahorros / ala
103-220898-44
Valor enviado
\$ 1.000.00`;
let m;

m = regex.exec(str)

console.log(m[1])
```